# Ansible: Permission denied

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm unable to run a playbook with public key authentication. I get this error:

> Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity:
>   /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private
>   key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity:
>   /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying
>   private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity:
>   /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not
>   send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication
>   methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password)

Till now, I have been using `--ask-pass` authentication, but now I need to automate it so I need to do it by public key. How have I to configure it?

I have found this playbook to do it:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    authorized_key_list:
      - name: root
        authorized_keys:
         - key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
           state: present
```

I execute this playbook with `--ask-pass` and next playbook execution doesn't require password and work fine. But after some minutes it doesn't! Why? What is playbook above actually doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not what's it will supposed to do, this will only go inside the machine B and check if the public key of machine A is present in authorized key or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have 2 machines. Machine A {Ansible Host} & Machine B{ target}

On the Machine A, you will have to generate a sshkey using :

```
~$ ssh-keygen
```

This will generate a Public and Private key pair in .ssh directory of your current user.

Once the keys are generated you need to copy the public key {extension .pub} from the Machine A's .ssh directory.

Now Login to Machine B , and go inside .ssh folder of it. Now you need to create a file called "`authorized_keys`" (if not present, make sure the permission is readonly) and paste the copied public key from Machine A to machine B.

This is done .

Now in your host{inventory} file on machine A use the following format :

```
 [hosts]
Machine_B_ip ansible_ssh_user=username_here ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path_of_private_key
```

ex:

```
    [log_export]
12.6.1.23  ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/nsingh/dev.pem
```

You can do a ansible ping also to check if Ansible is able to communicate via ssh as `ansible all -m ping -vi inventory_file`

Comment: Can you tell me which is the private key? `id_rsa` file?

Comment: yes exactly , id_rsa is the private key which u need to pass in the inventry file and id_rsa.pub is the public key which needs to be pasted in Machine B's authorized_key

Comment: And `ansible_ssh_user` is the remote user, doesn't it? I followed it step by step but I still get an error. Maybe some `sshd_config` is wrong?

Comment: what's the error ? what's the ansible version ?? And also see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html  ,


Notice : Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user, ansible_host, and ansible_port

Comment: or perhaps change the question according to the new configs and also paste the error .